# ¿Como abrir un formulario hijo en un mdi en pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

mi pregunta es como abrir un formulario [solo una vez en un mdi parent de pyqt5]

tengo una pequeña función escrita y si abre los formularios pero no se como evitar que ya no se abran mas que si ya esta creada la instancia a ese formulario que solo se muestre y la instancia activa o el formulario abierto se oculte.

```
def OpenForm(self,object):    

    self.GenericForm = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    window = object
    window.setupUi(self.GenericForm)
    subWindow = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow()
    subWindow.setFixedSize(981,591)
    subWindow.setWidget(self.GenericForm)
    subWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.ContainerMDI.addSubWindow(subWindow)
    self.GenericForm.show()
```

Su aplicacion es la Siguiente

```
 def OpenFormStudent(self):

    self.OpenForm(Ui_FormStudent())
```

Answer (score 1):

QmdiArea tiene un atributo llamado subWindowList que devuelve una lista de los objetos contenidos en si mismo. Puedes hacer una validación si tu elemento ya se encuentra dentro

```
def OpenForm(self,object):    

    self.GenericForm = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    window = object
    window.setupUi(self.GenericForm)
    self.subWindow = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow()
    self.subWindow.setFixedSize(981,591)
    self.subWindow.setWidget(self.GenericForm)
    self.subWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    
def open_subwindow(self):
    if self.subWindow not in self.ContainerMDI.subWindowList():
        self.subWindow.closeEvent = lambda event: event.accept()
        self.subWindow.setWidget(self.GenericForm)
        self.ContainerMDI.addSubWindow(self.subWindow)
    if self.subWindow in self.mdiArea.subWindowList():
        self.subWindow.show()
```

Lo que debes mostrar es la subventana, si ya la has abierto se debe encontrar en el listado. Entonces para no abrir varias ventanas únicamente lo volvemos a mostrar.
self.subWindow.closeEvent = lambda event: event.accept()
Esta linea la agregue por que al cerrar la ventana la mdi área no la elimina y ocasionaba un pequeño bug donde ocasionalmente no mostraba la ventana.
Mi modificación de tu código esta pensado en asignar la función a un botón.